# For an object in motion if $u=\hat i + \hat j$ and acceleration $a= \hat i + \hat j$ how will its parametric graph look like look like in $xy$-plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

1. I believe graph would be a straight line at 45 degrees from x axis and that would represent a 2D motion but one of my teachers said that if graph is a straight line then it is one dimensional motion. He said if you rotate reference axis the graph will be along $x$-axis or $y$-axis which is one dimensional motion therefore only curves on $xy$ plane represent 2D motion.
2. If acceleration is constant and non zero in both directions (i.e. $a= 5\hat i+ 3\hat j$) will parametric graph be always a straight line?
3. If acceleration is zero in both directions and velocity is constant in both directions as in following 2D motions are such motions also a 1D motion?
4. Motion of rain in wind is in oblique direction and described by vertical and horizontal vectors. Resultant motion is in straight line but studied under 2D motion. Why such motions are a 1D motion? And why studied under 2D motion?
5. If motion is given by y=mx+c. The motion seems to be 2 dimensional i.e. in xy plane. Are such motions also 1dimentional?
6. Is true that straight lines on $xy$ plane is always a 1D motion? If yes then a straight line in 3D motion is also a 1D motion. This is very confusing to me.

Point 4,5 and 6 are the remaining old and new doubts.

Answer (score 2):

If the initial position of the object is $\vec x(0)$, its initial velocity is $\vec u$ and its constant acceleration is $\vec a$, then its position at time $t$ is

$\displaystyle \vec x(t) = \vec x(0) + \vec ut + \frac 1 2 \vec a t^2$

In general this is *not* a straight line - it is a parabola. However, in the special case where $\vec u$ and $\vec a$ are parallel (as they are in your example, where $\vec u = \vec a = \hat i + \hat j$) then the two "sides" of the parabola collapse into a straight line, and you can think of this as one dimensional motion.

It is the difference between a ball thrown straight up, which travels up and down in a straight line, and a ball thrown at a non-zero angle to the vertical, which travels in a parabola.

Comment: Lets say if rain is falling vertically downward in -y direction and wind is blowing in +x direction. So motion of rain is in oblique direction. Is that motion also a one dimensional motion?

Comment: @Level1 If the motion is in a straight line then, yes, it is one dimensional motion.

Comment: I have edited the question and added some new doubts. Can you please include them in your answer. I find that there are mixed opinions on this topic. Is there any reason behind considering a 2D motion a 1D.

Comment: @Level1 Any motion that is confined to a straight line is one-dimensional motion. It would make no sense to use a definition in which motion was one-dimensional if co-ordinate axes were oriented in one way but two-dimensional if they were orientated otherwise.  You might as well add a z co-ordinate with constant value and say that the motion is three-dimensional. If you have have further questions you should make a new post.